# how to create an update method in c#

Tags: c#, methods

Im trying to create a method to update an input string with another input string. for example you set accountHoldername to james then you enter another acountHolderNAme matty. the update accountHolderName method should return back matty

```
 public class BankAccount
{

    private String accountHolderName;

    public  BankAccount ( double balance, String accountHolderName, long accountNumber)
    {
        this.accountHolderName = accountHolderName;
    }

    public long AccountNumebr
    {
        get
        {
            return accountNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            this.accountNumber = value;
        }
    }

    public String AccountHolderName
    {
        get
        {
            return accountHolderName;
        }
        set
        {
            this.accountHolderName = value;
        }
    }

    public double Balance
    {
        get
        {
            return balance;
        }
        set
        {
            this.balance = value;
        }
    }



    public String UpdateAccountHolderName()
    {


    }
```

}

Comment: you don't need another update method for that. Since your property has a setter, you can change it whenever you want in your code. As far as you describe it, the `set` is already your "updateValue". Example :  `var bankAccount = new BankAccount(); bankAccount.AccountHolderName = "James"; bankAccount.AccountHolderName = "Jane";"`

Comment: my assignment requires a UpdateAccountHolder method

Comment: would this work

        public String UpdateAccountHolderName(String UpdatedAccName)
        {
            UpdatedAccName = accountHolderName;
            return UpdatedAccName;
        }

Comment: `my assignment requires a UpdateAccountHolder method` Your assignment is likely based on other languages that lack the niceties of C#.

Comment: Sure you could add this method, but it defeats using public setters.  Bad design.  Worst case you have two different ways to update one property with different logic.

Comment: If your account holder name was private and couldn't be set as per the others have described above then it would make sense to have a method to do so, but as it stands there's no point.

Comment: does your assignment already provide the properties? or did you code them on your own?

Comment: yea it provides the properties. would it make more sence to make the properties private??

Comment: it would make sense to have the `set` private, maybe, in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want that method, use private setters for your property:

```
public class BankAccount
{
    public string AccountHolderName { get; private set; }

    //Note there's really no need for a return value here
    public void UpdateAccountHolderName(string newAccountHolderName)
    {
        AccountHolderName = newAccountHolderName;
    }
}
```

Granted, this is functionally equivalent to:

```
public class BankAccount
{
    public string AccountHolderName { get; set; }
}
```

An update method makes more sense here if you're updating multiple properties with it.

**Edit**

You can also do this if you really want:

```
public class BankAccount
{
    public string AccountHolderName { get; private set; }

    public string UpdateAccountHolderName(string newAccountHolderName)
    {
        AccountHolderName = newAccountHolderName;
        return AccountHolderName;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a requirement missing from OP's description, though : the function should return the value set.

Comment: @Pac0 The value set is being passed.  No need to return it.  But you could have it return `string` if you really wanted to.  This would be useful if there's a chance the input string != the return value.

Comment: " No need to return it." If this is an assignment requirement, then there is a big need to return it. The need to sattisfy the requirements of the assignment.

Comment: @Zer0 I completely agree it's uselss, as is this whole requirement to have another method other than the `set` ;o)

Comment: wouldnt the rturn value be accountHolderName?

Comment: @ktlava98 the return value is `accountHolderName` when you look at your own implementation where you have an explicit getter you will see that accessing the value of the `AccountHolderName` property will return the value of the private field `accountHolderName`

Comment: @ktlava98 if you use "automatic properties" as in this answer, then you don't have directly access to the backing field, which name will be slightly different (and hidden to the coder anyway). But you can simply return the argument `return newAccountHolderName`, or the property `return AccountHolderName`, since they are equal now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant to have it so that you couldn't set the various properties on the Bank Account publicly then it would look something like this:

```
public class BankAccount
{

    private string accountHolderName;
    private long accountNumber;
    private double balance;

    public  BankAccount (double balance, String accountHolderName, long accountNumber)
    {
        this.accountHolderName = accountHolderName;
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public long AccountNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return accountNumber;
        }
    }

    public string AccountHolderName
    {
        get
        {
            return accountHolderName;
        }
    }

    public double Balance
    {
        get
        {
            return balance;
        }
    }

    public string UpdateAccountHolderName(string accountHoldername)
    {
        this.accountHolderName = accountHolderName;
        return AccountHolderName;
    }
}
```

You can test this with a console app like this:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ba = new BankAccount(10.00, "Bob", 123456);

        ReadDetails(ba);

        var newName = ba.UpdateAccountHolderName("Frank");
        Console.WriteLine("New Name: " + newName);

        ReadDetails(ba);
    }

    static void ReadDetails(BankAccount ba)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Balance: " + ba.Balance + ", Name: " + ba.AccountHolderName + ", Number: " + ba.AccountNumber);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

It's worth noting that monetary amounts are normally done using decimal, so you might want to reconsider using double for the balance.

**UPDATE**
Now updated to return the new name as part of the method
[image]

Comment: There is no need for backing fields.

Comment: @Zer0 - agreed, though I took the view that the OP was choosing to write their code like this. As you had already demonstrated this as well it seemed a little unnecessary to do the same.

Comment: I figured as much.  Just wanted to briefly note this in case someone other than OP looks at this code.